# Using KerasTensor elements from previous layer to populate matrices in next layer

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I'm building a neural network using TensorFlow and I'm running into an error I was hoping to get some help with. I'm trying to take the output of a Dense layer and map its individual elements to a matrix in a subclassed layer. A simple example of what I'm trying to do is as follows:

```
# -------------------------------------------------------------
# Subclass layer
class subFunc(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
            
    def call(self,inputs):
        # Parse parameter outputs from Dense layer
        theta1 = inputs[0]
        theta2 = inputs[1]
        theta3 = inputs[2]
        theta4 = inputs[3]
        theta5 = inputs[4]
            
        # Populate matrices using above parameters
        A = np.array([[theta1,0],             # (2x2) matrix
                      [0,theta2]])            
        B = np.array([[theta3],[theta4]])     # (2x1) matrix
        C = np.array([[theta5],[0]])          # (2x1) matrix
            
        # --- Perform desired calculation ---
        # An example calculation; Replace w/ desired operations
        example_calc = np.matmal(A,B) + C
        return example_calc
    
# -------------------------------------------------------------
# Input values
x = np.random.rand(20)

# Build the model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(5,input_shape=(20,)))
model.add(subFunc())
```

I get a **NotImplementedError** when I try to run this with the following explanation:

> NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic tf.Tensor (sub_func_15/strided_slice:0) to a numpy array. This error may indicate that you're trying to pass a Tensor to a NumPy call, which is not supported.
>
> Call arguments received by layer "sub_func" (type subFunc):
> • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 5), dtype=float32)

**Is there a way I can go about this?** I recognize I'm using numpy arrays instead of Tensors to define my matrices, but I'm not sure if that's the real problem here (I'm still fairly new to using TensorFlow). I'm also aware that the output of the Dense layer is a KerasTensor, but I'm not sure how to use it to perform the way I'm hoping.

The above example is **not** my actual intended application, but this problem is what is currently causing my fully built model to break down. For my actual code, I **do** need to be able to take to outputs of a previous layer and populate the individual elements into matrices. Each matrix has a specified form needed to perform the desired calculations to get my final predicted output values.

Thanks,

Comment: You can't use numpy with symbolic tensors. Use tf operations and tensors. Instead of np.array, use something like tf.constant. Instead of np.matmul, use something like tf.linalg.matmul.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. So I replaced all `np.array` operations with `tf.constant` and similarly `np.matmul` with `tf.linalg.matmul`. I confirmed in a separate console that populating A,B,C with other numeric values it works fine. However, when I try to run the updated code within the class,  I get a **TypeError**   "A = tf.constant([[theta1,0],[0,theta2]]) --> TypeError: Expected any non-tensor type, but got a tensor instead." I believe this is the true issue I'm trying to address, but thanks for the fix using TensorFlow operations appropriately.

Comment: What are the `dtype`s of your `theta` variables? They're probably tensors but specifically what type? Also, which version of tensorflow?

Comment: So I found out that the `dtype` of all my `theta` variables are float32, which is what I was expecting. I also checked the shape of each `theta` variable and they're all (5,) which is not what I was expecting. That would explain the error I get for defining my A, B, and C matrices since the shapes do not match, but I'm confused as to why each of my `theta` variables all have shape (5,)? I was operating under the assumption I was accessing the  individual elements of the Dense output layer when defining my `theta` variables. I'm currently using TensorFlow 2.9.1

Comment: Maybe my answer is what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're after, but the `theta` variables are not single elements like you're probably expecting, but rather `tf.strided_slice` tensors with shape `(5,)`, even though your `inputs` tensor is the output from your Dense layer, with shape `(5,)`. If you try to get an element of the strided slice tensor, it will have shape `()`. `tf.constant` does not accept tensors, but `tf.convert_to_tensor` does. The passed iterables have to be of the same shape, so the `0` elements are lists of `0` with lengths the same as the tensor passed on the same row. `example calc` fails but that's going to be replaced so I didn't try further.

```
class subFunc(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def call(self, inputs):
        # Parse parameter outputs from Dense layer
        theta1 = inputs[0]
        theta2 = inputs[1]
        theta3 = inputs[2]
        theta4 = inputs[3]
        theta5 = inputs[4]

        # Populate matrices using above parameters
        A = tf.convert_to_tensor([[theta1, [0]*len(theta1),  # (2x2) matrix
                                  [0]*len(theta2), theta2]], dtype=tf.int32)
        B = tf.convert_to_tensor([theta3, theta4], dtype=tf.int32)  # (2x1) matrix
        C = tf.convert_to_tensor([theta5, [0]*len(theta5)], dtype=tf.int32)  # (2x1) matrix

        # --- Perform desired calculation ---
        # An example calculation; Replace w/ desired operations
        example_calc = tf.linalg.matmul(A, B) + C
        return example_calc
```

Comment: So I think we're getting closer to the solution, but not quite there yet. So your above code fixes the error I was getting when defining my A,B,C matrices. However, I need my `theta` variables to be single elements so that the shape of my A matrix is (2x2), and my B,C matrices to be (2x1). If I were to remove the `model.add(subFunc())` line from my model, it would only be a a single, fully connected layer with an output of 5 individual values of dtype float32. I'm just wanting to individually access those output elements for a user-guided calculation using the specific outputs.

Comment: According to https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/shape, when using graph mode (which I believe you are), the function that gives more information on the shape is `tf.shape()`, which shows the shape of `inputs` as `(2,)`. When I do `for i in inputs:`, the loop only executes one time. But the third element (which would be OOB according to `tf.shape` has shape `(1,)`. So I'm lost on why this is happening. Maybe you could try to run a more complete model in EagerExecution and see what happens.

Comment: I just did `tf.shape(inputs[10])` and went up to index 20, which should 100% be out of bounds, `tf.shape()` still outputs `Tensor("sub_func/Shape:0", shape=(1,), dtype=int32)`